# C# AllocConsole Redirect Input

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I have a Winforms application that I would like to use the console with, so far I've called this by using AllocConsole() and can successfully print things to the window by Console.WriteLine as expected.

However, the user is unable to type into the window. Is there something I'm missing or is this impossible to achieve?

EDIT 1: Tried using the SetConsoleMode Pinvoke but am still unable to input to the console window. Code shown below:

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    private enum ConsoleModes : uint
    {
        ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT = 0x0001,
        ENABLE_LINE_INPUT = 0x0002,
        ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT = 0x0004,
        ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT = 0x0008,
        ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT = 0x0010,
        ENABLE_INSERT_MODE = 0x0020,
        ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE = 0x0040,
        ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS = 0x0080,
        ENABLE_AUTO_POSITION = 0x0100,
        ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT = 0x0001,
        ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT = 0x0002,
    }

    #endregion
    public Form1()
    {
        AllocConsole();
        Console.WriteLine("Hi.. Write Below");
        IntPtr ConInt = GetConsoleWindow();
        SetConsoleMode(ConInt, (uint)ConsoleModes.ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT);

        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

Comment: SetConsoleMode might help.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033.aspx